# How can I change color of selected option in Sidebar using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble figuring out how to change the color of the selected option in a sidebar. For example, I have 4 options, and I click the first option, I want the first option in the sidebar to have a white background color all the time. All I have now is just a hover option, where it changes the background color. Can I have this with only using CSS HTML? From my research, I saw a few in JavaScripts and PHP, but wonder if I can do this using only CSS HTML. Below is my current code:

```css
.flexContainer {
    display: flex;
}

.flexContainer > div {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}

.sidebarContainer {
    flex-shrink: 1;
}

.sidebar {
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #dd1d5e;
    overflow: auto;
    border-radius: 30px;
}

.sidebar a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #dd1d5e;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexContainer">
            <div class="sidebarContainer">
                <div class="sidebar">
                    <a href="category.php">Holiday</a>
                    <a href="category.php">Vegetarian</a>
                    <a href="category.php">Dessert</a>
                    <a href="category.php">Cultural Cuisine</a>
                </div>
            </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to make it work in standalone HTML without PHP. Firstly, you should have 4 HTML files, and each file should be a different name, say cat-holiday.htm, cat-vegetarian.htm, cat-dessert.htm and cat-cultural.htm.

After that, each HTML file has a ONE `<a>` contains a special CSS classname, say: `.selected`. Sample of cat-holiday.htm

```
            <div class="sidebar">
                <a href="category.php" class="selected">Holiday</a>
                <a href="category.php">Vegetarian</a>
                <a href="category.php">Dessert</a>
                <a href="category.php">Cultural Cuisine</a>
            </div>
```

Finally, you could add a corresponding code to your CSS file.

```
.sidebar a.selected {
    background-color: #ff0000;
    color: #00ffff;
}
```

Comment: Hi, if I want to make this possible with PHP, how should I approach it? I'm trying to use GET method to do it, but I'm having a hard time understanding how it works...

Comment: You could retrieve the URL parameter (GET method) by `$_GET`, and replace the `class="selected"` by PHP, such as `<a href="category.php?c=1" <?php if ($_GET['c'] == '1'){ echo 'class="selected"';} ?> >`

Answer (score 0):

You can add this CSS code to your CSS:

```
 .sidebar a:nth-child(1){
        background-color: #ffffff!important;
        color: #dd1d5e!important;
}
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Updated snippet below.

```css
.flexContainer {
    display: flex;
}

.flexContainer > div {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}

.sidebarContainer {
    flex-shrink: 1;
}

.sidebar {
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #dd1d5e;
    overflow: auto;
    border-radius: 30px;
}

.sidebar a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #dd1d5e;
}

 .sidebar a:nth-child(1){
        background-color: #ffffff!important;
        color: #dd1d5e!important;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexContainer">
            <div class="sidebarContainer">
                <div class="sidebar">
                    <a href="category.php">Holiday</a>
                    <a href="category.php">Vegetarian</a>
                    <a href="category.php">Dessert</a>
                    <a href="category.php">Cultural Cuisine</a>
                </div>
            </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to define a class called "active" with the style you want to apply to a selected option in the sidebar. Then append the class to the anchor-tag currently selected.

```css
.flexContainer {
    display: flex;
}

.flexContainer > div {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}

.sidebarContainer {
    flex-shrink: 1;
}

.active {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #000000 !important;
}

.sidebar {
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #dd1d5e;
    overflow: auto;
    border-radius: 30px;
}

.sidebar a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #dd1d5e;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexContainer">
            <div class="sidebarContainer">
                <div class="sidebar">
                    <a href="category.php" class="active">Holiday</a>
                    <a href="category.php">Vegetarian</a>
                    <a href="category.php">Dessert</a>
                    <a href="category.php">Cultural Cuisine</a>
                </div>
            </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your question was how to make the link I click on change its background color.

```css
.flexContainer {
    display: flex;
}

.flexContainer > div {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}

.sidebarContainer {
    flex-shrink: 1;
}

.sidebar {
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #dd1d5e;
    overflow: auto;
    border-radius: 30px;
}

.sidebar a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar a:hover {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #dd1d5e;
}

a:focus {
    background-color: yellow;
    color: #00ffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexContainer">
            <div class="sidebarContainer">
                <div class="sidebar">
                    <a href="#" >Holiday</a>
                    <a href="#">Vegetarian</a>
                    <a href="#">Dessert</a>
                    <a href="#">Cultural Cuisine</a>
                </div>
            </div>
</div>
```